# Is there some tool to convert a cython codebase back to pure python?

Tags: python, benchmarking, cython, pypy

I'd like to do some real life benchmark comparing cpython+cython performances vs a pure pypy implementation.

I have a quite big cython codebase (proprietary), with a good test coverage and some benchmarks, what I'd like to do is to test cython performances against pypy, but what I miss is a fast way to share the code.

- Is there some tool to strip all type annotations and convert back a cython codebase to a pure python one?
- Or is there some parser extension in pypy to accept cython code ignoring all the type annotations? (or even use them...)
- Other options?

Comment: It sounds like you're using Cython as an accelerator.  While this is a perfectly valid use-case, it's important to recognize that it's not the *only* use case.  Cython is also designed to interface easily with C code, and that would be nontrivial to translate (into the equivalent ctypes/CFFI calls).  So a *general-purpose* tool would be more complicated than I think you may be imagining it to be.

Comment: There is pure-Python mode: http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pure.html.

Comment: @Kevin you are right, in this specific case there are some sip (the PyQt one) wrapped C++ classes, but a very limited number. In that case cpyext should be enough. And 80% working converter (the easy 80%, leaving the hard 80% left as exercise) could be a good starting point.

Comment: At that point, you're going to be maintaining a copy of the pure-Python module in version control anyway, so the tool is significantly less useful.  You can just go through and manually strip out all the `cdef`s; a short Perl script could probably do it.

Comment: @Kevin I was in fact searching for that kind of tool, a brute script to do a bare one-shot benchmark.